# Sending data from React form to Firebase database

Tags: forms, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a form in React and wanting to send the data collected to the Firebase database. However, I'm not entirely sure on how to set this up efficiently. I have posted below some snippets of some of the code I have so far.

Here is the beginning of my component. From my understanding the `componentDidMount` is pulling the data from the `json` file to have into those fields. But I'm not sure if that is where I should enter the code to send to Firebase.

```js
class FormContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      startDate: moment(),
      courseName: '',
      courseCity: '',
      courseStateOptions: [],
      courseStateSelection: '',
      holeNumberOptions: [],
      holeNumberSelection: '',
      yardage: '',
      clubOptions: [],
      clubSelection: ''
    };
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleClearForm = this.handleClearForm.bind(this);
    this.handleFirstNameChange = this.handleFirstNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handleLastNameChange = this.handleLastNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
    this.handleDateChange = this.handleDateChange.bind(this);
    this.handleCourseNameChange = this.handleCourseNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handleCourseCityChange = this.handleCourseCityChange.bind(this);
    this.handleCourseStateSelect = this.handleCourseStateSelect.bind(this);
    this.handleHoleNumberSelect = this.handleHoleNumberSelect.bind(this);
    this.handleYardageChange = this.handleYardageChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClubSelect = this.handleClubSelect.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('./nhior_db.json')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          firstName: data.firstName,
          lastName: data.lastName,
          email: data.email,
          date: data.date,
          courseName: data.courseName,
          courseCity: data.courseCity,
          courseStateOptions: data.courseStateOptions,
          courseStateSelection: data.courseStateSelection,
          holeNumberOptions: data.holeNumberOptions,
          holeNumberSelection: data.holeNumberSelection,
          yardage: data.yardage,
          clubOptions: data.clubOptions,
          clubSelection: data.clubSelection
        });
      });
  }
```

Below this I have all of my `handleFirstNameChange()` functions, etc.. I won't post them all in here, but here are a few for reference.

```js
  handleCourseNameChange(e) {
    this.setState({ courseName: e.target.value }, () => console.log('course name:', this.state.courseName));
  }
  handleCourseCityChange(e) {
    this.setState({ courseCity: e.target.value }, () => console.log('course city:', this.state.courseCity));
  }
  handleCourseStateSelect(e) {
    this.setState({ courseStateSelection: e.target.value}, () => console.log('course state', this.state.courseStateSelection));
  }
  handleHoleNumberSelect(e) {
    this.setState({ holeNumberSelection: e.target.value}, () => console.log('hole number', this.state.holeNumberSelection));
```

Then I have my `handleClearForm()` and `handleFormSubmit()`

```js
  handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formPayload = {
      firstName: this.state.firstName,
      lastName: this.state.lastName,
      email: this.state.email,
      date: this.state.date,
      courseName: this.state.courseName,
      courseCity: this.state.courseCity,
      courseStateSelection: this.state.courseStateSelection,
      holeNumberSelection: this.state.holeNumberSelection,
      yardage: this.state.yardage,
      clubSelection: this.state.clubSelection
    };

    alert('Thanks for the submission!');
    // console.log('Send this in a POST request:', formPayload)
    this.handleClearForm(e);
  }
```

Lastly the `render` method contains all the inputs, here are a few.

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <form className="container" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
        <h6>If you are one of the SPECIAL FEW to make a hole in one, you have the opportunity to record your success in the national registry!
          Please enter your information, the date of your Hole-In One and click Continue.</h6>
          <SingleInput
            inputType={'text'}
            title={'First name'}
            name={'name'}
            controlFunc={this.handleFirstNameChange}
            content={this.state.firstName}
            placeholder={'First Name'} />
          <SingleInput
            inputType={'text'}
            title={'Last name'}
            name={'name'}
            controlFunc={this.handleLastNameChange}
            content={this.state.lastName}
            placeholder={'Last Name'} />
          <SingleInput
            inputType={'text'}
            title={'Email'}
            name={'name'}
            controlFunc={this.handleEmailChange}
            content={this.state.email}
            placeholder={'Email'} />
          <DatePicker
            selected={this.state.startDate}
            onChange={this.handleDateChange}/>
```

I just need to know if there is a better more efficient way to send the data collected to Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking two questions:

- where I should enter the code to send to Firebase, and
- how to set this up efficiently.

The answer depends on what you mean by "efficient".

To simply get your example to work, you add the firebase call inside `handleFormSubmit`, right where your console.log is. But you probably knew that.

So what's efficient? If you want to organize your code in a manageable way, then a good start is a state framework like [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) or [Redux](http://redux.js.org/). It is a good idea to keep most of your state (i.e. data you get from firebase) in one place.

I use [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux), and essentially separate my logic into 2 kinds of controllers. One controller (often called async functions or thunks) handles your database fetching/saving and the other controller prepares (maps) your data and event handlers for the view. This way I rarely use `this.setState(...)` or `this.state` and get a clear, unit-testable separation of concerns.

With your example, you would `dispatch` an async action (in redux terminology) in `handleFormSubmit`, and have this action push data to firebase and reflect the change (e.g. saving status) in the global state `store`. Then you simply render your component with data passed from the store into the props.